# Check data structure and impute missing values

Tags: r, dataframe

Have some stock data for example as shown below and have created random missing values. Would want to create a function to check the data structure of the data.frame, if the data is continuous, calculate the percentage of missing values and if the percentage of missing values is greater than 40% then omit the row and if less than 40% impute the mean for the same.

If the data is categorical calculate the percentage of missing values and if the percentage of missing values is greater than 40% then omit the row and if less than 40% impute the mode for the same.

```
comp <- c('F','F','F','S','S','S','T','T','T')
month <- c('Jan','Feb','March','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sept')
Sales <- c('Low','Medium','High','High','Low','High','Medium','Low','Low')
bq1 <- runif(9,min = 0, max = 100)
bq2 <- runif(9,min = 0, max = 100)
bq3 <- runif(9,min = 0, max = 100)
bq4 <- runif(9,min = 0, max = 100)
bq5 <- runif(9,min = 0, max = 100)
bq6 <- runif(9,min = 0, max = 100)

df <- data.frame(Comp = comp, Month = month, Sales = Sales, Qtr1 = bq1, Qtr2 
= bq2, Qtr3 = bq3, Qtr4 = bq4, Qtr5 = bq5, Qtr6 = bq6)



 df[5,5] <- NA
 df[5,4] <- NA
 df[5,7] <- NA
 df[5,9] <- NA


 df[3,5] <- NA
 df[3,4] <- NA
 df[3,7] <- NA
 df[3,9] <- NA

df[9,5] <- NA
df[9,4] <- NA
df[9,6] <- NA
df[9,8] <- NA

df[7,5] <- NA 
df[1,5] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) -> df1

#imputation function
impute <- function(x){
  missing_perc <- sum(is.na(x))/length(x) * 100
  return(ifelse(missing_perc > 40, NA, 
                ifelse(is.character(x), names(sort(-table(x[!is.na(x)])))[1], mean(x[!is.na(x)]))))
}
impute_val <- sapply(df1, impute)

#impute missing values
df1[] <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, is.na(x), y), df1, impute_val)
#drop rows where column has missing percentage > 40
df1 <- na.omit(df1)

#final data
df1
```

**Output is:**

```
  Comp Month  Sales             Qtr1             Qtr2             Qtr3             Qtr4             Qtr5
2    F   Feb Medium 65.4017299879342 66.0814035916701 13.8528823154047 21.5696093859151 18.2194353546947
4    S   Apr   High  89.403684460558 74.2279292317107 55.5751067353413  51.869766949676 9.31410894263536
6    S  June   High 11.7533272597939 11.6908136522397 12.5517533393577 95.4095394117758  36.061190161854
8    T   Aug    Low 7.48507694806904 77.5027731899172 42.0926807913929 11.0406906111166  17.137353355065
              Qtr6
2 82.1378237567842
4 27.7001850772649
6 88.5877252323553
8 23.5045042354614
```

**Sample data:**

```
structure(list(Comp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("F", "S", "T"), class = "factor"), Month = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 9L), .Label = c("Apr", "Aug", "Feb", 
"Jan", "July", "June", "March", "May", "Sept"), class = "factor"), 
    Sales = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("High", 
    "Low", "Medium"), class = "factor"), Qtr1 = c(43.4887288603932, 
    65.4017299879342, NA, 89.403684460558, NA, 11.7533272597939, 
    50.5520776147023, 7.48507694806904, NA), Qtr2 = c(NA, 66.0814035916701, 
    NA, 74.2279292317107, NA, 11.6908136522397, NA, 77.5027731899172, 
    NA), Qtr3 = c(5.68129089660943, 13.8528823154047, 35.6186878867447, 
    55.5751067353413, 6.98710139840841, 12.5517533393577, 8.91167896334082, 
    42.0926807913929, NA), Qtr4 = c(22.5347936619073, 21.5696093859151, 
    NA, 51.869766949676, NA, 95.4095394117758, 16.6109931422397, 
    11.0406906111166, 56.1983718769625), Qtr5 = c(5.67050215322524, 
    18.2194353546947, 88.5992815019563, 9.31410894263536, 77.7505977777764, 
    36.061190161854, 51.1230558156967, 17.137353355065, NA), 
    Qtr6 = c(27.9433359391987, 82.1378237567842, NA, 27.7001850772649, 
    NA, 88.5877252323553, 50.3849557833746, 23.5045042354614, 
    74.2521224310622)), .Names = c("Comp", "Month", "Sales", 
"Qtr1", "Qtr2", "Qtr3", "Qtr4", "Qtr5", "Qtr6"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```